# Finding maximum of minimum for every window size in a given array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

An integer array A[] of size N is given.The task is to find the maximum of the minimum of every window size in the array.
Note: Window size varies from 1 to n.

E.g:arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 50, 10, 70, 30}

Output:     70, 30, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10

I understood how the output came But I am really having trouble in understanding the algorithm.I understood the naive approach but the solution that involves O(n) is quiet tricky to understand.The code for O(n) is attached below:

```
import java.util.Stack; 
class Test { 
static int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 50, 10, 70, 30}; 
static void printMaxOfMin(int n) 
{ 
    // Used to find previous and next smaller 
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>(); 

    // Arrays to store previous and next smaller 
    int left[] = new int[n+1]; 
    int right[] = new int[n+1]; 

    // Initialize elements of left[] and right[] 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    { 
        left[i] = -1; 
        right[i] = n; 
    } 

    // Fill elements of left[] using logic discussed on 
    // https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/ 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    { 
        while (!s.empty() && arr[s.peek()] >= arr[i]) 
            s.pop(); 

        if (!s.empty()) 
            left[i] = s.peek(); 

        s.push(i); 
    } 

    // Empty the stack as stack is going to be used for right[] 
    while (!s.empty()) 
        s.pop(); 

    // Fill elements of right[] using same logic 
    for (int i = n-1 ; i>=0 ; i-- ) 
    { 
        while (!s.empty() && arr[s.peek()] >= arr[i]) 
            s.pop(); 

        if(!s.empty()) 
            right[i] = s.peek(); 

        s.push(i); 
    } 

    // Create and initialize answer array 
    int ans[] = new int[n+1]; 
    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) 
        ans[i] = 0; 

    // Fill answer array by comparing minimums of all 
    // lengths computed using left[] and right[] 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    { 
        // length of the interval 
        int len = right[i] - left[i] - 1; 

        // arr[i] is a possible answer for this length 
        // 'len' interval, check if arr[i] is more than 
        // max for 'len' 
        ans[len] = Math.max(ans[len], arr[i]); 
    } 

    // Some entries in ans[] may not be filled yet. Fill 
    // them by taking values from right side of ans[] 
    for (int i=n-1; i>=1; i--) 
        ans[i] = Math.max(ans[i], ans[i+1]); 

    // Print the result 
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) 
        System.out.print(ans[i] + " "); 
} 

// Driver method 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    printMaxOfMin(arr.length); 
} }
```

The above attached code can be found on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-of-minimums-for-every-window-size-in-a-given-array/

Comment: There's a detailed explanation on the [website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-of-minimums-for-every-window-size-in-a-given-array) you linked to. What parts did you have difficulty with?

Comment: I have difficulty in understanding from the step two of this approach @גלעדברקן

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using just one doubly ended queue and a single loop.

```
    while q and a[end] < q[-1]:
        q.pop()
    q.append(a[end])
```

After each iteration q[0] will be min.